# nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar when swipe back

Tags: uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have made a nested tableview with navigation controller. When I select a row of the table, i get pushed to the new tableview. The navigation controller shows the back button to go back to the previous tableview. All this work fine as long as I touch the cell and use navigation controller to go back.

However, when I touch the cell to move to next tableview, and swipe from left to right to go back to the previous tableview, i am able to go back but the navigation bar gets corrupted. Then when i click the cell again to move to the next view controller I get following error "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"

Comment: Wait: the error is actually _telling_ you not to use a nested push animation and that it will corrupt the navigation bar, and then you are surprised when the navigation bar is in fact corrupted?

Comment: I am not surprised that the navigation bar gets corrupted. I am expecting it to get corrupted. But my question is why does it get the error when i use the swipe back gesture and its fine when i use the back button of the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I was experiencing this because I embedded navigation controller in one of the tabs of the tabbed bar controller. The correct way to do it explained here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html